# How can i embed a video object in a container?

Tags: javascript, video, embed

there is some code where a pdf-file gets embedded to open up in a new window. Now the question is how I can embed video files as well? Or even all types of files.

```
    window.open($scope.newurl + $scope.file, "", "width=200,height=100");
    //var myPDF = PDFObject.embed($scope.newurl + $scope.file, "#documentDetailContainer", options);
```

with pdfObject embed, the file gets loaded into the documentdetailcontainer, because the url used is actually a download (getfile) from a certain location. Which is not inside the webapp, so i can't just open it. That part worked.

Now i'm trying to replace that somehow so I can include videos as well. But when i just use window.open, it opens a new window and just downloads it.

My question is: How can i load this into the container instead of just downloading it?

Comment: is this a javascript or a c# question?

Comment: I'm sorry, its javascript